# Launching node of rosserial_python in gazebo launch script

Tags: arduino, ros

I am using Gazebo simulation. I want to connect arduino to my model in Gazebo. I used following coding in the gazebo launch script:

```
<node pkg="rosserial_python" type="serial_node.py" name="rosserial" output="screen">
<param name="port" value="/dev/ttyACM0" />
<param name="baud" value="57600" />
</node>
```

when I launch the gazebo with `roslaunch` command the following error apeares:

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [rosserial_python/serial_node.py]: can't locate node [serial_node.py] in package [rosserial_python]
```

Does anybody know about my problem?

Comment: Can you run the node with `rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this:
<arg name="port"  default="/dev/ttyACM0" />
<node name="serial_node" pkg="rosserial_python" type="serial_node.py">
        <param name="port" value="$(arg port)"/>
        <param name="baud" value="57600" />
</node>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit why you think this will solve the problem? The only difference I see is that an `arg` is used for the port but that will not solve the issue that the node is not found.